# Why is "citizenfour" a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I understand that people might reference the movie in a question.  But shouldn't the tags for that question be related to the security technology/technique they're asking about, and not which movie it may or may not be used in?

Otherwise I'd suggest creating a Hackers tag... a Swordfish tag...

Comment: bloody hell you're not wrong. WTH? Next time just edit the q and remove the stupid tags.

Comment: // , It's not just a movie.

Comment: What else is it?

Comment: // , citizenfour is an actual historical pseudonym for people in his position.

Comment: // , Not a huge difference, but it's the sort of basis in history to which other "hacker" movies can not lay claim.

Comment: @NathanBasanese I still wouldn't call say that someone "in his position" is on topic for this forum.

Comment: /* @NathanBasanese I'm pretty sure comments don't have to have comment syntax */

Comment: # @corsiKa, /*Commenting*/ (*at*) --least REM 'makes <!---it---> C obvious -{they're-} // comments !Make %sure <#to#> [use them as often as possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_%28computer_programming%29).